# DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed

Tags: service-worker

I was playing with service workers recently. I wrote some code in my Service  worker file and suddenly it broke. Does anybody have any idea what does "ServiceWorker script evaluation failed" means and when possibly can it come?

Comment: I left an answer, but you might want to include the code you have in your SW in the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Normally it means that there is a syntax error in the SW and the browser couldn't parse it.

Comment: Chrome will display the service worker errors in the console and you can also use the Dev Tools > Application > Service Workers page to see the number of errors next to the service worker file name.